# Adding Numbers and printing the sum vertically using arrays

Tags: java, arrays, loops, compiler-errors, sum

I have to create a program which adds two integers and prints the sum vertically.
For example, I have.

```
a=323, b=322.
```

The output should be:

```
6
4
5
```

I've created the code for when the integers are up to two digits, but I want it to work for at least three digits.

Below is the best I could think of.
It may be completely wrong, but the only problem I'm facing is the declaration of array.
It says that the array might not be initialized.
If I set it to null then also it won't assign values to it later.

I know maybe I'm making a big mistake here, but I'll really appreciate if anyone could help me out.
Please keep in mind that I must not use any other functions for this code.
Hope I'm clear.

```
public class Vert
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int n,i=0,j,a=323,b=322;
        int s[];
        n=a+b;
        while(n>9)
        {
            s[i]=n%10;
            i++;
            s[i]=n/10;
            if(s[i]>9)
            {
                n=s[i];
            }
        }
        j=i;
        for(j=i;j>=0;j--)
        {
            System.out.println(+s[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `+s[j]` That looks like it could be a problem... What **is** the error, though?

Comment: As a side note, think about a case such as ``789`` and ``456``: what should the result be?

Comment: @cricket_007 Error is "S might not be initialized" and if I assign "null" to s[] then it wont assign any other value to it later. I wanna know how to initialize that array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String conversion seems like cheating, so here's a `Stack`.

```
int a = 323, b = 322;

java.util.Stack<Integer> stack = new java.util.Stack<>();

int n = a + b;
while (n > 0) {
    stack.push(n % 10);
    n = n / 10;
}

while (!stack.isEmpty())
    System.out.println(stack.pop());
```

---

If an array is required, you need two passes over the sum

```
int a = 323, b = 322;

// Get the size of the array
int n = a + b;
int size = 0;
while (n > 0) {
    size++;
    n = n / 10;
}

// Build the output
int s[] = new int[size];
n = a + b;
for (int i = size - 1; n > 0; i--) {
    s[i] = n % 10;
    n = n / 10;
}

// Print
for (int x : s) {
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much but can you explain the for loop you used to print, because I'm not familiar with that format. Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to print the output using "simple" for loop instead of the one with the " : " operator. Thanks

Comment: There is, but it's an enhanced for loop, and I trust your ability to search the internetz and learn the differences

Answer (score 1):

To initialize an array, you need to specify the size of your array as next:

```
int s[] = new int[mySize];
```

If you don't know the size of your array, you should consider using a `List` of `Integer` instead as next:

```
List<Integer> s = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Here is how it could be done:

```
// Convert the sum into a String
String result = String.valueOf(a + b);
for (int i=0; i <result.length();i++) {
    // Print one character corresponding to a digit here per line
    System.out.println(result.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: How do you determine `mySize`?

Comment: @cricket_007 frankly speaking I don't really get what the OP wants to achieve, I simply try to answer his initial question

Comment: If this is an assignment, I'm not sure his teacher will like to see a `List` here. If he doesn't want to hardcode the size from the number of digits or count the number of digits beforehand at runtime, he should just scrap the array and print the digits as they come (like with a local variable)...

Comment: OP would like to print the sum of digits vertically. Seems like an array is required. Though, one would think `String.valueOf(n)` and straight printing the digits would be the answer

Comment: @cricket_007 ok I see now

Comment: @cricket_007 oh my you're right. I forgot that the digits would be printed backward if the OP scraps the array... That was a big derp of my part... However using a string instead of an array, like you said, would be a good solution too.

Comment: @OliPro007 Yeah. I provided the array answer since it would seem that is required.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

```
int a = 322;
int b = 322;
int sum = a + b;
String s = Integer.toString(sum);
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
  System.out.println(s.charAt(i));
}
```

But your problem looks like an array is required.

The steps are same as in my solution:

1. Use int values
2. Sum the int values (operation)
3. Convert the int value in an array/string
4. Output the array/string